# Is CPU utilization a predictable time series?

Tags: time-series, arima, random-walk, forecastability

I've been wondering whether metrics about CPU and resource utilization is a time series which can be predicted or rather a random walk which I cannot learn from. Can recognizing a pattern in the data or using some moving average be useful for prediction in this case?

I have seen some publications suggesting that it is a problem which we can apply ARIMA model on but it seems not logical to me because there are so many factors that affect the CPU usage in a way that the usage history becomes useless.
Would love to hear your opinion, thanks!

Comment: This may depend on how fine your time scale is. You could probably predict that usage is low at night and high at daytime, high on weekdays and low on weekends.

Comment: And if we take one hour between observations and try to predict the next 10?

Comment: Average utilization over the whole hour or more or less instantaneous utilitzation, say, over a second at some fixed point within the hour?

Comment: The latter, some instantaneous sample of the CPU utilization every x time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your goals. I am not knowledgeable about CPU, so I cannot answer the question. However, with the added information I hope someone else will be able to answer it better.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable because it can have any answer depending on assumptions about the demands on the CPU and how the operating system manages those demands.  Perhaps if you could supply sufficient information about those details we could get beyond that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much information beyond that at the moment since I need to check this in the general case. However, what techniques do cloud service providers use to control and predict the resource management?

Comment: Forecasting various compute utilization resources is one of the most common use cases for large scale time series forecasting, probably right after demand forecasting and streaming data use cases. It comes in very useful for teams that are charged with planning and managing large data centers or various other big data compute hardware. The pattern actually tend to be more interesting and cleaner than in more business oriented time series data like retail.